# angular2 ng-cli: unable to add twitter-bootstrap to index.html

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I recently started a angular2 web app using ng-cli.  i'm trying to add Twitter-bootstrap (which I installed with npm) to my index.html file.  For some reason it doesn't seem to find bootstrap even though the path is correct.  Am I missing something?  Is ng-cli moving bootstrap somewhere else?

My code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular cli does not work the way you are doing. it add third party library like below.

1. add install library  using NPM

   npm install bootstrap@next
2. add your script and style files in apps[0].scripts and apps[0].styles properties of angular-cli.json. like

   ```
       apps": [
       {
         "root": "src",
         "outDir": "dist",
         ......

         "styles": [
           "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
           "styles.css"
         ],
         "scripts": [
           "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
           ],
         "environments": {
           "source": "environments/environment.ts",
           "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
           "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
         }
       }
     ],
   ```

after adding like this. it will add all the files into index.html